# Submit Hive query in Visual Studio, how?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, hive, azure-hdinsight

Okay, so yesterday I had a toolbar button labeled "Submit". Now, nothing. Either my SDK 2.7 update clobbered it, or I inadvertently dismissed a toolbar. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the Azure Tools 2.7. How do I submit my Hive query?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the latest version VS Express is not supported, so you might want to use Visual Studio Community instead (which is also a free VS SKU).
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
Sorry for the inconvenience!